# How to import in F#

Tags: import, f#

I have a file called `Parser.fs` with `module Parser` at the top of the file. It compiles. I have another module in the same directory, `Main`, that looks like this:

```
module Main

open Parser

let _ = //do stuff
```

I tried to compile `Main.fs` with `$ fsharpc Main.fs` (idk if there's another way to compile). The first error is `module or namespace 'Parser' is not defined`, all other errors are because of the fact that the functions in `Parser` are not in scope.

I don't know if it matters, but I did try compiling `Main` after `Parser`, and it still didn't work. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

F#, unlike Haskell, does not have separate compilation. Well, it does at the assembly level, but not at the module level. If you want both modules to be in the same assembly, you need to compile them together:

```
fsharpc Parser.fs Main.fs
```

Another difference from Haskell: order of compilation matters. If you reverse the files, it won't compile.

Alternatively, you could compile Parser into its own assembly:

```
fsharpc Parser.fs -o:Parser.dll
```

And then reference that assembly when compiling Main:

```
fsharpc Main.fs -r:Parser.dll
```

That said, I would recommend using an `fsproj` project file (analog of cabal file). Less headache, more control.